# A contract works in remix but not when used with truffle

Tags: truffle, remix

Below is the contract:

```
uint32 firstTimeUserPoints=10;
    struct struUser{
        string orginalName;
        string originalKshoplink;
        string orginalDocumentConvention;
        bool validated;
        uint32 Points;
        uint32 totalPoints;
    }
    struct struUserTotalPoints{
        string orginalName;
        uint32 totalPoints;
    }
    mapping(string=>struUser)MappingToken;
    mapping(bytes32=>struUser)SampleMappingToken;
    struUser[] struUsers;
    struUserTotalPoints[] struArrayUserTotalPoints;
    string[] docConventionMappers;
    string[] orginalName;

//TO INSERT A RECORD WITH SOME DATA

function AddUser(string name,string link,string docConvention) public
{
        var user=MappingToken[docConvention];
        var existingTotalPoints=userTotalPoints(name);

        user.orginalName=name;
        user.originalKshoplink=link;
        user.validated=false;
        user.Points=firstTimeUserPoints;
        user.totalPoints=existingTotalPoints+firstTimeUserPoints;
        updateUserTotalPoints(name,user.totalPoints);
        user.orginalDocumentConvention=docConvention;
        docConventionMappers.push(docConvention);

        struUsers.push(struUser({orginalName:name,originalKshoplink:link, 
        validated:user.validated,Points:user.Points,totalPoints:user.totalPoints,
        orginalDocumentConvention:docConvention}));

    }

//IS THE BELOW FUNCTION FINE?, THIS IS ONE OF THE PLACE I BELIEVE IT IS GETTING MESSED.

//FOR FETCHING TOTAL POINTS OF A USER

 function userTotalPoints(string name) public returns(uint32){  

         bool isUserTotalPointsCalculated=false;

            for(uint j=0;j<struArrayUserTotalPoints.length;j++){
                if(keccak256(struArrayUserTotalPoints[j].orginalName)==keccak256(name)){                    
                    isUserTotalPointsCalculated=true;
                    return struArrayUserTotalPoints[j].totalPoints;
                }
            }
            if(!isUserTotalPointsCalculated){
                struArrayUserTotalPoints.push(struUserTotalPoints({orginalName:name,totalPoints:firstTimeUserPoints}));
                return 0;                
            }  
    }
//WHEN I CALL THE BELOW METHOD IT IS RUNNING FINE IN REMIX BUT NOT WHEN I USED WITH TRUFFLE - IN TRUFFLE THE STRING IS  RETURNED AS " " AND THE TOTAL POINTS 

    function viewuser(string docConvention)public returns(string,uint32,uint32)
{ 
        return (MappingToken[docConvention].orginalName,MappingToken[docConvention].Points,
        userTotalPoints(MappingToken[docConvention].orginalName));
    }

    function updateUserTotalPoints(string name,uint32 totalPoints) public{
        for(uint j=0;j<struArrayUserTotalPoints.length;j++){
                if(keccak256(struArrayUserTotalPoints[j].orginalName)==keccak256(name)){
                    struArrayUserTotalPoints[j].totalPoints=totalPoints;
                }
            }
    }
```

I have tried for different inputs and it is working fine.

#### Remix inputs:

[image]

#### Remix outputs:

[image]

#### HTML:

```
<input id="txtViewUser" type="text" placeholder="Enter name of document convention" />
<button id="btnViewUser" onclick="App.viewUser()">View User</button>
```

#### Truffle code:

```
viewUser:function () {
    var docConvention=document.getElementById("txtViewUser");
    sampleinstance.deployed().then(function (instance) {      
        return instance.viewuser.call(docConvention).then(function (v) {
        console.log(v);
        $("#tdEmailName").text(v[0].toString());
        $("#tdPoints").text(v[1].toNumber());
        $("#tdTotalPoints").text(v[2].toNumber());
      })
    })
  },
```

#### Truffle Output:

```
the 0 array will return the name of the user
```

I have inserted different users five times so it is giving 50 where I have tried to view user for one person.

[image]

Kindly help me out in analyzing where I am going wrong please.

Vivek.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it may be working as expected but you did not understand to expect BigNumber format. This is decoded for you by Remix.

BigNumber is a way to represent a number that has more significant digits than JS can handle (uint256).

Try converting your function responses to a readable format.

`console.log(response.toString(10));`

If that is the right answer, then consider reading up on BigNumber library that is included in Web3.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. Tried - console.log(v.toString(30)); but still no luck. output is something like " ,10,20". Still i am missing the string value. How do i get the string output?

Comment: `v.toString(10);`

Comment: even tried v.toString(10) earlier still it's the same.